# JAVA BCEL NEWARRAY getType Basic Type

Tags: java, bytecode, bcel

How do I in BCEL check for this..

Say the bytecode in java is

```
newarray 10 (int)
```

I got this already done for visitor

```
instruction instanceof NEWARRAY

public boolean visit(Instruction instr) {
    return instr instanceof NEWARRAY;
}
```

But I also have to check if the newarray is `int[]`

how do I check this in BCEL?

I tried this

```
 && ((NEWARRAY) instr).getType() == Type.INT;
```

to well

```
return instr instanceof NEWARRAY && ((NEWARRAY) instr).getType() == Type.INT;
```

But you can see the above ^ will not work as it will never be `int`.. but `int[]`

But `Type.INT` is just `int`.. and not `int[]`..

How I represent Type `int[]`?

I was reading the BCEL source code and NEWARRAY.getType() returns this..

```
     /**
      * @return type of constructed array
      */
     public final Type getType() {
         return new ArrayType(BasicType.getType(type), 1);
     }
```

As you can see it returns a `Type` class so.. looking at 
http://commons.apache.org/bcel/apidocs/org/apache/bcel/generic/Type.html

http://commons.apache.org/bcel/apidocs/org/apache/bcel/generic/ArrayType.html

there isn't any `Type`'s for ARRAY `int[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I understand your question well, but what about this:

```
if(instr.getClass().isArray()) return instr instanceof NEWARRAY[];
else return instr instanceof NEWARRAY;
```

Comment: well NEWARRAY is a bytecode instruction.. in java asm  I doubt NEWARRAY[] exists lol.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why `((NEWARRAY) instr).getType() == Type.INT`  doesn't work.. well `getTypecode()` gives me `10`..